How can I verify a claim from my JWT token with reactive spring security?
I have an application for which my users require an access authority to use the application. As such I did the following:
@Bean
fun filterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain = http {
    csrf { disable() }
    formLogin { disable() }
    logout { disable() }
    httpBasic { disable() }
    authorizeExchange {
        authorize(anyExchange, hasAuthority("access"))
    }
    oauth2ResourceServer { jwt {} }
}

Now I would like to add an additional check for a specific claim. I want to verify the contents of the resource_access claim from within my token and more specifically the presence of a key there.
Basically what I would like is something like this:
authorize(anyExchange, hasAuthority("access") && hasResourceAccess("my-resource"))

I've been trying to find how I can do this without having to redefine everything and in a reactive-supporting way.
A few options that I've tried but haven't been able to see through:
1/ OAuth2TokenValidator
I have tried creating my own but I'm stuck at being able to set it as a JwtValidator. Looks like I need to define a ReactiveJwtDecoder but it requires an issuer-uri that I don't have access to.
@Bean
fun jwtDecoder(): ReactiveJwtDecoder =
    (ReactiveJwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(issuerUri) as NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder).apply {
        setJwtValidator(MyAccessValidator())
    }

2/ ReactiveAuthorizationManager<AuthorizationContext>
I could create my own but then I'm not sure how I can combine both the AuthorityReactiveAuthorizationManager and mine. I guess I could bundle both logics in my own but I'd like a solution where I can reuse what is already existing.
I wanted to use DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager but it seems I cannot because it's a ReactiveAuthorizationManager<ServerWebExchange> and not a ReactiveAuthorizationManager<AuthorizationContext>
I could rewrite it but I guess there is something that already exists that I just wasn't able to find.

So, digging a bit more I found out the following simple enough solution.
I created my own ReactiveAuthorizationManager although considering how I used it I could have done with a simple Function.
fun hasResourceAccess(resource: String) = ReactiveAuthorizationManager<Any?> { authenticationMono, _ ->
    authenticationMono
        .mapNotNull {
            val jwt = it.principal
            if (jwt is Jwt) jwt.getClaimAsMap("resource_access")
            else null
        }
        .map { AuthorizationDecision(it.containsKey(resource)) }
        .defaultIfEmpty(AuthorizationDecision(false))
}

An I used it this way
@Bean
fun filterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain = http {
    csrf { disable() }
    formLogin { disable() }
    logout { disable() }
    httpBasic { disable() }
    authorizeExchange {
        authorize(anyExchange) { authenticationMono, authorizationContext ->
            Flux
                .merge(
                    hasAuthority("access").check(authenticationMono, authorizationContext),
                    hasResourceAccess("my-resource").check(authenticationMono, authorizationContext)
                )
                .all(AuthorizationDecision::isGranted)
                .map(::AuthorizationDecision)
        }
    }
    oauth2ResourceServer { jwt {} }
}

